# iOS Scene Kit display ply model with vertex color

Tags: ios, scenekit, ply-file-format

I have this iOS app that is trying to display a 3d model with iOS Scene Kit.

The ply 3d model shows up fine without color properties (r,g,b,a)

However, after adding some color properties, Scene Kit gives an error called: Unrecognized type 'uchar'

Would it work if we change the type of the properties? Or is it just because SceneKit just cant display vertex color?

Would really appreciate it if somebody could shed some light

I have attached the PLY file below

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
element vertex 92869
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property uchar alpha
element face 184532
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
-3.79316 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.78155 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.76995 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.75834 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.74674 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.73513 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.72352 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.71192 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255 
-3.70031 -2.28398 0 255 255 255 255
```